# How to create list of interest in FLUTTER app

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

what I'm trying to do is to have something like this by building an app in Flutter:
[image]

I Have a list of interest and I want to have this kind of card (autosized based on numbers of character) for each of those, I have no fixed number of columns and each row is filled by the right number of elements based on the number of character and I have all the rows needed in order to print all interest in List.

Which is the right widget that I have to use?

I tried with listview but I have only one element for row, I can use multiple columns but this means I have a fixed number of columns.
I tried also with GridView, but again I have to fix the crossAxisCount (to fix number of columns).

I have no idea,

TY

Comment: Those are called "Chips". Check out this guide: https://medium.flutterdevs.com/chip-widgets-in-flutter-7a2d3d34597c

Comment: The guide is very helpful! thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should use `wrap` for your need.